# XCode: how to duplicate a project properly

Tags: xcode, macos

i've got a good working project (a plugin) and i would like to be able to duplicate that project with another name to start on the same basis (and not having to rebuild everything every time)

I can of course duplicate the main folder and rename the files and change the names in the code but it's a lot of work and sometimes it doens't work as good as i want.

So is there an automated way to duplicate a project ?

thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Make sure to take backup of your project before following these steps.**

do you want to rename your project after making a copy of it? You can do this. Select project on top and press `Tab` button.

[image]

And if you want to rename a class name then goto your .h file then follow 2nd  screenshot. Doing this will rename entire class and its references in all other classes.

It will modify source code of `xib` also. Earlier this process was having some bugs but I dint try it on latest `XCode5`. Give it a try.

[image]

Comment: Well, the question here is totally different from the answer given. The OP asks how to properly duplicate/copy a project.

Comment: Good use of refactor though :)